# Enable SSL for your Wordpress site google cloud

Tags: ssl, cloud

I am new to google cloud.
I go to the market.
I launch a wordpress site.
I am not able to enable ssl for newly created wordpress site.
I am having ssl certificate from cloudflare.
How to add ssl certificate from cloudflare to wordpress on google cloud.
Please help me.
Sincere thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using google domains services or other provider , try to contact their support to install SSL manually

Or try this tutorial :

https://onepagezen.com/cloudflare-cdn-wordpress-google-cloud/